# Comparing membership of a list with True operator

Tags: python, python-2.7, conditional-statements

Let's say we have

```
a = [1, 2]
```

Then in the interpreter,

```
for e in a: print e in a
```

prints

```
True
True
```

BUT the following code doesn't make sense to me or any of my python-expert friends

```
for e in a: print e in a == True
```

prints

```
False
False
```

Can someone explain this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If we boil the confusing expression down, it is:

```
1 in a == True
```

This gives `False` (we might have expected `True`).  So let's use the `ast` module to inspect it:

```
>>> import ast
>>> print ast.dump(ast.parse('1 in a == True'))
Module(body=[
  Expr(value=Compare(
      left=Num(n=1),
      ops=[In(), Eq()],
      comparators=[
        Name(id='a', ctx=Load()),
        Name(id='True', ctx=Load())
      ]))
  ])
```

Compare with a version with added parentheses which works the way you'd probably expect:

```
>>> print ast.dump(ast.parse('(1 in a) == True'))
Module(body=[
  Expr(value=Compare(
      left=Compare(
        left=Num(n=1),
        ops=[In()],
        comparators=[
          Name(id='a', ctx=Load())
        ]),
      ops=[Eq()],
      comparators=[
        Name(id='True', ctx=Load())
      ]))
  ])
```

Do you see the difference?  The second one is like `Eq(In(1, a), True)` as we'd expect.  But the first is `In(1, a) Eq(a, True)`.  What?  How do those two things go together?  Well, they form a conjunction, like `and`.

So it ends up that the first expression is equivalent to `1 in a and a == True`.

But why?

It's because Python supports "chained conditionals," like this:

```
1 < 3 < 5
```

Your example is just collateral damage: apparently not only are conditionals like `<` chained, but `in` counts too.  This isn't intuitive to me, but that's how it works.  You can read more about chaining here: https://docs.python.org/2/reference/expressions.html#not-in

Comment: Isn't the first comparison saying `In(1, a) Eq(a, True)`? Otherwise it would return `True`, since `1 == True` is `True` but `a == True` is `False`, right?

Comment: @Neftas: you are correct.  It was a simple typo in my answer.  It's fixed now.  Thank you.